# Simple SQL questions for date format

Tags: sql, date

how to find the minimum date from the date column? if the date contains the format of date is 1996-07-04.

Comment: Hint:  Use the function `MIN()`.

Comment: please add your dbms tag sql is language

Answer (score 1):

Min function will give you the desired result.

e.g

```
SELECT  MIN(date) FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax :- `SELECT MIN(COlumn_Name) FROM Table_Name`
Eg:-       `SELECT MIN(OrderDate) AS Min_OrderDate FROM Table_Name`